# Absolute cheapest/simplest voltage booster? (for High side Mosfet Switch)

Tags: mosfet, 555, charge-pump

what is the absolute cheapest solution to provide gate voltage for a high side switch?
I will have to use NFETs due to 20A+ cont. with low losses.

There is no switching happening (think of a load switch) and I have 12VDC and 5VC available with common ground.
My idea was to use a 555 in a charge pump circuit and add 12V to 12V-5V (using 5V as 555s GND) to achieve 19VDC. Yet a CMOS 555 costs at least 0.20cts and seems to sophisticated of a chip to use for a charge pump :) .
I can also use a cheap bipolar one but I want to know whether I am missing out on something?
I didn't consider a Boost regulator, because few do >12V and the output (NFET gates) doesn't consume any power and I think inductor etc is over the top (also costs somewhat)

**Am I missing an obvious solution?**

Thank you!

**Edit 1:** I didn't want to offend anyone with the word "cheap", I was curious whether I missed an obvious solution. Also I have learned so much already reading through this forum, maybe some day someone will have the same question I have and be thankful for your answer.

Edit 2: Thanks for the feedback, the voltage is used to turn on/off 12V with the Mosfet.

(I have no microcontroller in my project, also I prefer using Mosfets (NFETs) rather than dedicated Load switches due to high current and better availability/cross compatibility in common form factors)

Comment: Where do you want to spend your money?  Invest thousands in engineering time to save a few cents or chose a solution that just works but pay a little extra per unit?

Comment: "cheap" is not a good design spec. (-1) Use a list of design specs instead to include On time, Off time, space and cost, current consumption and EMI as well as V+ from Vbootstrap or charge pump.

Comment: Attenbach, if you want regulated output then 3 BJTs, a zener, a schottky, 3 resistors, and 2 caps. Oh, and you get to wind your own transformer (very simple, one wire threaded in a toroid in a certain way.) LTspice says it works off of a 5 V rail. I haven't built one, though. No specs. It will just do what it does. Well, it works with up to *about* 3 mA load. *About* is also not much of a spec. ;) But the idea is sound and no boutique ICs or MCUs.

Comment: Why is being 'absolute cheapest/simplest' so important?

Comment: Cheap does not correspond with simplest. Why do you need it cheapest? Are you actually making thousands of these?

Comment: You mention 12 V and 5 V, but do not say how those two voltages are related to the voltage being switched by the MOSFET.  Nowhere in your question do you say the voltage level that the high-side switch is switching, or the part number of the MOSFET.  This is critical information for designing a gate drive circuit.  Please update your question with this information.

Answer (score 1):

There are many solutions - bootstrap IC, charge pump, self-oscilating step-up converter...

I like this type of circuit where only one transistor and small tranformer with few turns is need (the balast around I dont count):

[image]

[image]

The blue is 12v power-suplly, green is boosted voltage refered to ground.

I didnt tune it much, the self-consumtion can be much lower. If your 12V is stable you dont need a close-loop controll, just use zener to limit boosted voltage as I did.

Answer (score 0):

Build an oscillator and pump using a CMOS 4049 hex inverter, a capacitor and two diodes. A CD4011 (quad NAND) will also work.